# Detecting Web.Config Authentication Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config

Say I have the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Using ASP.NET C#, how can I detect the Mode value of the Authentication tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType`

Go for PB's answer folks

Comment: I have accepted your answer because yours was the quickest and worked :)

Comment: This is wrong.  In the general case IIdentity.AuthenticationType can contain any string, which may not necessarily match the authentication mode set in web.config.

I'd use the solution from @pb.

Answer (score 29):

The mode property from the authenticationsection: [AuthenticationSection.Mode Property (System.Web.Configuration)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.authenticationsection.mode(VS.80).aspx). And you can even modify it.

```
// Get the current Mode property.
AuthenticationMode currentMode = 
    authenticationSection.Mode;

// Set the Mode property to Windows.
authenticationSection.Mode = 
    AuthenticationMode.Windows;
```

This article describes [how to get a reference to the AuthenticationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.authenticationsection(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 12):

Import the `System.Web.Configuration` namespace and do something like:

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
var authenticationSection = (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
if (authenticationSection.Mode == AuthenticationMode.Forms)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: You should use application root "~" instead of site root "/", but better to call WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication") directly

Answer (score 5):

You can also get the authentication mode by using the static  [`ConfigurationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get the section and then the enum `AuthenticationMode`.

```
AuthenticationMode authMode = ((AuthenticationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication")).Mode;
```

[The difference between WebConfigurationManager and ConfigurationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

---

If you want to retrieve the name of the constant in the specified enumeration you can do this by using the `Enum.GetName(Type, Object)` method

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(AuthenticationMode), authMode); // e.g. "Windows"
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Core you can use this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
{
    var enabledAuthTypes = config["IIS_HTTPAUTH"].Split(';').Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

use an xpath query  //configuration/system.web/authentication[mode] ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
 config.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
 XmlNode node = config.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/system.web/authentication");
 this.Label1.Text = node.Attributes["mode"].Value;
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't work in the general case.
An ASP.NET app inherits settings from machine.Config and from all other web.config files higher in the virtual directory tree: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx
Your technique only looks at the lowest web.config file.

Comment: XPath is not something that should be used to parse the configuration by any means. Utilizing the libraries provided by MS is a far more efficient and maintainable approach. The comment above is a perfect example of why not to use it as well as the fact that not all platforms will have necessarily utilize the configuration documents for authentication or other settings; another valid case is if the location of the authentication type is changed, then you must replace a hardcoded string, recompile, then redistribute.