# .Net Configuration files confusion

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

We've got a somewhat complex project that the original developers split into multiple projects for organization purposes.  What this means to me is that I've got an ASP.Net site that has a web.config and contains all sorts of good settings, and another project that compiles to a DLL that has it's own .config file, app.config.

In the DLL, it would be very nice to be able to access all the AppSettings that I have in the ASP.Net proejct's web.config file.

Is this possible?  Is it good practice?  I don't really want to copy and paste the same information and have to manually keep them in synch between the 2 (actually there might be up to 20 -- it's a large project and someone organized it to an absurd level) .config files.

Any suggestions or best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually default behavior - `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` read the current `web.config` for all DLLs.
Sometimes `.config` files are created for other projects (or dlls), but they are not used in the site and should be merged into `web.config`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was trying to test, but I was scared I would miss some odd combination of circumstances when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) accesses the `web.config` from any class library. Just be sure to add a reference to `System.Configuration` and `System.Web` to any library needing to access this.

And to answer your question about standard pratice, yes it is common to store application key/values in the web.config to keep things centralized in ASP.NET web applications and web sites. In your web.config just use the `<appSettings>` section as you normally would in app.settings files.

Comment: You're right, but why would you reference `System.Web`? You can just reference `System.Configuration`, and everything should be fine, eg. getting an app setting through `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Comment: Fair enough. I tend to use the additional functionality found in WebConfigurationManager specific to web apps, so I prefer it. If simply finding name-value pairs is all  the OP needs, ConfigurationManager may be the better solution...

Comment: Good discussion of the two managers and their use:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationma/698163