# How to retrieve non <appSettings> keys from the web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is there a .NET built-in way to retrieve `executionTimeout` value?  Perhaps via ConfigurationManager set of objects?  I don't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any section can be retrieved from using [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx)

```
var httpRuntimeSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as 
HttpRuntimeSection;

//httpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout
```

[ExecutionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx)

In Web app we could use [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151430.aspx) that also has similar API - [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151434.aspx)

[ConfigurationManager vs. WebConfigurationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)