# Reading value from web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

From my DAL, How can i read a connection string from the web.config?

Comment: I did search prior to posting but totally forgot to add the System.configuration reference to my DAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WebConfigurationManager to read connection string value from web.config

Code Example:

```
using System.Configuration;

string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Make sure you have added the System.configuration reference to your DAL.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Configuration;

static string connectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
```

Yuu only need `WebConfigurationManager` if there are several Web.Config files in your project using data connection strings:

[What's the difference between the WebConfigurationManager and the ConfigurationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString
```