# Is there an option to read the web.config key value from aspx?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configurationmanager

Checking there are any option to read the config values directly from aspx page (I know how to read using codebehind).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029873/reading-value-from-web-config-file/13029891#13029891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution

```
<%$  appsettings:*KeyName* %>
```

here keyname is the actual name in web.config also note you need a $ Symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing in your aspx page using some server tags e.g.

```
<% Dim s as string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("mysetting") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ConfigurationManager` and the`OBJECT` tag.

**Web.Config**

```
</configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Setting" value="Value"/>
    <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**ASPX**

```
<object>
    <param name="Setting" value="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"] %>" />
</object>
```