# How to enumerate endpoints urls?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service. It uses settings from configuration file.
It contains some sub-services working via http, net.tcp etc.
I'd like to create a method which will return all configured endpoints urls.
It will be used to provide client app possibility to receive url strings.

How I can do it inside of WCF service?

Comment: Why not have the client app just get the service metadata?

Comment: There are multiple services hosted inside of WCF service. Also, some of services have few enpoints (it may be http, net.tcp etc). To get a service metadata need to know its url. I want to provide a RESTful method, client app can query and get all endpoints addresses and then do what it needs. That is the client config utility. At least it will display addresses.

Comment: *To get a service metadata need to know its url.* - the whole point of exposing metadata is you want other people to know the URL.

Comment: To get service metadata via URL you need to know one URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
    private static List<Uri> GetClientsInfo()
    {
        var adressList = new List<Uri>();
        var clientSection = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection);
        if (clientSection != null)
        {
            foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endPoint in clientSection.Endpoints)
            {
                adressList.Add(endPoint.Address);
            }
        }

        return adressList;
    }
```

Also you can use "WebConfigurationManager" instead "ConfigurationManager" (depends of your Application type, more here [What's the difference between the WebConfigurationManager and the ConfigurationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm))