# SqlConnection giving object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I have to use connection string for my query, but I am getting an error

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my code:

```
string strSql = "select first_name + ' ' + last_name name, email from user_mst where mkey in (" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + ")";

DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter dbdata = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn))
    {
        dbdata.Fill(table);
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

I get error at

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
```

but my connections seems to be exactly fine.

Comment: Try modifying your code to assign `string conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();` and use the `conString` variable in your connection declaration. Likely the `ConnectionString` element doesn't exist in your configuration file. This will at least let you debug your code a little better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @gmiley: can u post a similar answer for that ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your web.config? Something is odd in your code. Why you use AppSettings to read the connectionstrings section?

Comment: Well, I could if you want, but it really isn't an answer IMO, just a suggestion to help debug your problem.

Comment: @gmiley: i tried ur way like this `string conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {` still getting the same error

Comment: You are using `AppSettings` and should probably be using `ConnectionStrings`.

Comment: @DavidG: yes but it's giving me error :(

Comment: Can you clarify if your connectionstring is contained in an AppSettings section or in the ConnectionStrings section of your web.config?

Comment: Also, after stripping out any sensitive information (name/password) please post the section of your config file containing your connection string.

Comment: @Steve: it is in the `connectionstring` section of config file

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Configuration`. Move your connection string in the connection strings section in your config file and get it with `string s =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested, here is the modified code should make it easier to debug, or at least just catch the missing connection string configuration element.

```
    string conString = string.Empty;
    try
    {
       conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve 'ConnectionString' from configuration file.");
    }
    string strSql = "select first_name + ' ' + last_name name, email from user_mst where mkey in (" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + ")";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dbdata = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn))
        {
            dbdata.Fill(table);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

After debugging your code, your problem appears to be stemming from your configuration file and how you are accessing your Connection String. Changing your code from:

```
try
{
   conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
}
catch(Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve 'ConnectionString' from configuration file.");
}
```

to

```
try
{
   conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
}
catch(Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve 'ConnectionString' from configuration file.");
}
```

Assuming the ConnectionString entry is also named "ConnectionString", this should solve your problem.

TLDR: As mentioned a few times in comments, change `AppSettings` to `ConnectionStrings` will fix your problem.

Comment: it went in catch `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Where does that exception get thrown?

Comment: at `catch (Exception)`

Comment: Ok, that is correct then, that's what it is intended for. That means we definitely have a problem with your config file. As I mentioned above, if you could include the relevant section from your config file, we can get this fixed quickly.

Comment: i got it, just changed it from `AppSettings` to `Connectionstring` and it worked

Comment: Just like it was said in the comments above...

Comment: @davidg: yes u wer right..thanks for ur comments

Answer (score 1):

Please check AppSettings in web.config properly .I am sure db path that you write in appsetting is wrong .

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString())` is returning `null` and then passed to SqlConnection constructor.
Check if your configuration file is valid and it contains key named `ConnectionString`. Something like this:
`<add key="ConnectionString" values="[your connection string]"/>`

Comment: yes it contains the values, I have checked it

Answer (score 0):

Usually the connectionstrings are stored in a proper section of your web config. This section is easily read by the WebConfigurationManager and it is stored in the ConnectionString collection

```
// You need this reference to System.Web.Configuration.dll
// and remove the using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

....
string cons = WebConfiguration.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cons))
.....
```

Also, while probably in your context using ConfigurationManager will work as well, you really should use the WebConfigurationManager for web applications

[See ConfigurationManager vs WebConfigurationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

Comment: so, should I remove `using` and directly use that. Also I don't have any issue in config file

Comment: session contains proper value . I checked it

Comment: Absolutely no, why do you want to remove using? It is always required to using around a disposable object

Comment: ohh, getting error as `string does not contain a definition for connectionstring`  this is the code `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))`

Answer (score 0):

Tostring() will throw an exception when written inside a using statement, I don't know why but I too faced this problem. Your code should be like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter dbdata = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn))
    {
        dbdata.Fill(table);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

you have to add reference to System.Configuration in your project by right clicking "References" and "add reference" in assemblies->Framework before using this code.