# Error: The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm attempting to use the following code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application

```
//add these using statements
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;

//this is an optional property to hold the secret after it is retrieved
public static string EncryptSecret { get; set; }

//the method that will be provided to the KeyVaultClient
public static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

    if (result == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

I am attempting to add the code above to a class in a c# class library, and to fix the error, I have tried the answer in the following thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/1205345.aspx?The+type+or+namespace+name+Configuration+does+not+exist+in+the+namespace+System+Web+. The suggested answer was: You need to add System.Configuration DLL via "Add Reference" dialog box. Right click References and select Add Reference, then select System.Configuration under the .NET tab.

However, when I try to add the System.Configuration DLL as a reference, I don't see it in the list. [image]

**Where can I find this System.Configuration DLL please?**

================== UPDATE ======================

Adding Assemblies-related screenshots. There are no options to add System.Configuration assemblies:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the WebConfigurationManager and the ConfigurationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698157/whats-the-difference-between-the-webconfigurationmanager-and-the-configurationm)

Comment: On Assemblies. and search System.Configuration

Comment: @D-Shih I added 2 screenshots. I have no options to add assemblies.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I wasn't able to find where in that thread it talks about how to import `System.Web.Configuration` into the project.

Comment: You have two problems: first, .NET standard is all NuGet based. You won't find anything as references. Second. `WebConfigurationManager` is for ASP.NET projects, which yours isn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both commenters of the original post were correct. I'm just going to sum up the answer here:

1. I needed to create a .NET Framework class library, not a .NET Standard class library because `WebConfigurationManager` is only available for .NET Framework.
   [image]
2. Right click on the class library's References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Find both `System.Web.dll` and `System.Configuration.dll` -> OK.

No more error!